# A program that checks specified part of web page and sends notification

Tags: internet, website, notifications

I have a web page - a list of items that doesn't change its structure - and need to get a notification when the item/s of interest change.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a feed at [Page2RSS](http://page2rss.com/) and add it to your favourite feed reader program (for example, Google Reader).

Answer (score 1):

I created a service which does this: http://atonofmonkeys.com

It provides a bookmarklet which allows you to select the area of the page you wish to moniitor. The service will check the webpage daily and send you a notification email with the details of any changes.